# “J'aurais manqué” vs “je manquerais”

Tags: temps-grammatical, conditionnel, temps-composés

> S'il lui **arrivait** quoi que ce soit, **j'aurais manqué** à ma promesse envers ses parents.
>
> S'il lui **arrivait** quoi que ce soit, je **manquerais** à ma promesse envers ses parents.

Translation: *If anything **happened** to her, my promise to her parents **would** go up in smoke.*

This sentence seems to call for the use of the *conditionnel passé* "j'aurais manqué", but for some reason I feel inclined to use the *conditionnel présent* "je manquerais".

Why do you need to use "j'aurais manqué" rather than "je manquerais"? How do these two versions differ in meaning?

Comment: arrivait -> manquerais, était arrivé -> aurais manqué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il faut appliquer la pure concordance des temps:

- S'il lui **était arrivé** quoi que ce soit, j'**aurais manqué** à ma promesse envers ses parents.
- S'il lui arrivait quoi que ce soit, je manquerais à ma promesse envers ses parents.

On peut éventuellement mélanger ici (*S'il lui arrivait ..., j'aurais manqué ...*). Le conditionnel passé note alors l'antériorité. Mais cela vaut aussi en anglais (*If anything happened to her, my promise would have gone up.*) or l'auteur de la phrase d'origine a choisi la concordance.

Le problème ici vient plutôt à mon avis de la traduction de "happened", qui dénote une action située précisément dans le temps, que l'imparfait rend mal - voire pas du tout en français. Il faudrait sur-traduire: "Si **à un moment** il lui arrivait quelque chose".